# Performance issue in Javascript library dtree.js

Tags: javascript, performance

In my application (developed way back in 2006), the developers used dtree.js ([Link](http://destroydrop.com/javascripts/tree/)) to render a hierarchy tree.  The problem occurred when in 2010 the tree grew to 1300 nodes and depth of upto 13 levels.  After this, the page started loading very slowly and in IE it gives the infamous "Stop running this script?" error.  I want to improve the performance, but all my tricks have failed:

1. Caching variables, DOM elements.
2. Calculating array lengths outside loops.
3. Minimizing use of loops.

Apart from this, I tried to used setTimeout() to break the execution in smaller tasks, but I am not able to get it working as it has many restrictions.  Also, I cannot move the rendering of tree to server side.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Sid

Answer (score 1):

Typically what is slow in any browser is anything to do with the DOM.

If you can lazy-load any part of the tree's HTML representation, do it.

In general try to minimize the number of times your edit the DOM.

Example:

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1) {
    dom_element.innerHTML += data.some_data;
}
```

vs

```
var string = "";
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1) {
    string += data.some_data;
}
dom_element.innerHTML += string; // only one call to innerHTML, likely much faster!
```

innerHTML is also faster than using DOMDocument-style (`document.createElement`, `element.append` and so on)

Comment: In my code, the innerHTML call is just once, but dtree.js inherently has lots of loops.  With 1200 nodes, it's taking a hell lot of time.

Comment: Just once, or just once for each node? In the former case you are indeed reduced to optimizing the JavaScript code. Keep in mind that no user will ever need to 'see' 1300 nodes at once. Anything that isn't shown doesn't have to be rendered ;)

Comment: No, just once for all nodes. The loops create a string which is then inserted in a <span> element.
Regarding the rendering, the data that is coming in is unordered and the loops iterate to find the parent child relationships.  So we need the entire data.

Comment: Yes, you need the entire data set, but you don't need to render it all simply because the user can not use 1300 nodes at once. It can become very complex very quickly, but such is the fate of optimization.

Comment: I agree.  My plan now is to render the top nodes first.  The data will as such be in Javascript, so I will render the inner nodes on click of the '+' for a parent.